# error Unit does not take parameters scala

Tags: scala, list

How can I print the element of List after each iteration?

```
scala> def carry(c: Int, list: List[Int]):List[Int] = (c, list) match {
     |
     |   case (0, xs) => xs
     |
     |  case (1, Nil) => List(1)
     |
     |  case (1, x :: xs) => println(x,xs)((1 - x) :: carry(x, xs))
     |
     |   case (_, _) => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input!!!")
     |   }
<console>:18: error: Unit does not take parameters
        case (1, x :: xs) => println(x,xs)((1 - x) :: carry(x, xs))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your call to `println(x, xs)` returns a `Unit` type, and you're trying to call the return value with argument `(1 - x) :: carry(x, xs)`. Perhaps you already knew that. Curly braces are your friend here, as they create a contained expression. Here's the solution:

```
case (1, x :: xs) => {println(x, xs); (1 - x) :: carry(x, xs)}
```

or

```
case (1, x :: xs) => {
  println(x, xs)
  (1 - x) :: carry(x, xs)
}
```